# Is there a way to reload a component on routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

This is my Usercomponent.ts

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit{

  cards: Cardint[];
  mySubscription: any;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService , private arrayService: ArrayService, public cardService: CardService,private router: Router,) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cardService.getcards().subscribe( cards => {
      this.cards=cards;
  })
  }

book='BookNow'

  onUserClick(card)
  {
      this.arrayService.card = card;
  }

}
```

this is my Cardservice.ts

```
export class CardService {
  cards: Observable<Cardint []>
  cardCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Cardint>;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.cards= this.afs.collection('cards').valueChanges();
   }

 getcards(){
   return this.cards;
 }

}
```

my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { path: "", component: UserComponent},
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    { path: "signup", component: RegisterComponent},
    { path: "ticket", component: TicketComponent},
    { path: "user", component: UserComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Problem: I am getting data(card details) from firebase in the ngOnit method using cardservice . Initially  I am getting the data but when I navigate to some other component and return back , data is not retreived.

I think the problem is with the onInit method because it is called once when component creates.
So I thought of reloading or refreshing the component(usercomponent) after navigating.

Suggest a way to solve this issue . I am very new to angular , if there is any silly mistake please do forgive .

Answer (score 0):

Set the onSameUrlNavigation property of the RouterModule like so. This forces the component to reload on navigation even if the url didn't change.

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
```

})],